# Android - Removing a dialog themed activity

Tags: android

Android 2.1 via eclipse

I have an activity that opens a dialog themed activity via checkbox onChecked function

Im creating this new dialog themed activity with an Intent.

Problem is, how do i dismiss the dialog themed activity once i finish with it? (the way it stands now, i have to send a new intent in order to go back to the previous activity via click of a button)

Any help would be greatly apprieciated!

Code snippet:

Main activity:

```
cbReminder.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked)
        {                   
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DateTimeDialog.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

Dialog themed activity:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.b_datetime_save)
    {

    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.b_datetime_cancel)
    {
        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MakeNoteActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: finish() should do that job, are you sure you're not overriding Activity history in any way?

Comment: Yeah, i used finish(), but i from some reason added the intent, thank you, saved me a damn good couple of minutes.

Comment: so you didn't test it with just the finish() before adding the Intent? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you specified, the intent was indeed not needed to return to the previous activity and should be removed.

To uncheck the checkbox after returning from the dialog, you can use `startActivityForResult` and set a callback for when you return.

Open your dialog like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), DateTimeDialog.class );
startActivityForResult( intent, UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER );
```

Then add a callback to that same activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data )
{
    if ( requestCode == UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER )
    {
        cbReminder.setChecked( false );
    }
}
```

The `UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER` can be any number that uniquely identifies this dialog. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: yeah its working fine, but i have another problem now, i need to uncheck the checkbox in the main activity once i finish with the dialog themed activity, any idea how?